# What does `ssh-keygen -r` do if a public key is not specified?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen

### Short Question

I'm assuming that `ssh-keygen -r hostname` uses a default public key. I would have thought that it would default to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, but that does not appear to be the case. So what *is* it doing?

### Long Version

My experience with the OpenSSH command-line utilities is that they either prompt the user for any missing arguments or fall back to standard default values. But for `ssh-keygen -r` this does not appear to be the case. When I run the `ssh-keygen -r` command without specifying a public key (e.g. `ssh-keygen -r hostname`), I get the following output:

```
no keys found.
```

I would expect it to default to my public key, e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. However, this does not appear to be the case, since when I pass in this public key explicitly (e.g. `ssh-keygen -r hostname -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) I instead get output of the following form:

```
hostname IN SSHFP 1 1 5d6c87ef4e8f4f59974f05723ff3dc0cffc9c4b4
hostname IN SSHFP 1 2 8fa151e7f3ba43fa89c240ab236f0313aea1fe9f9e9f4e5b8f084ca0008399ed
```

Moreover, the man page for `ssh-keygen` shows the following syntax for the `ssh-keygen -r` command:

```
ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
```

Since the `-f input_keyfile` flag is denoted as being optional, I would expect `ssh-keygen` to do something other than just print an error message.

So, if `ssh-keygen -r hostname` does not use `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` as its default public key, and it doesn't prompt the user to specify a public key, then what *is* it doing? Is it defaulting to some other path? If so, what path is that?

**NOTE:** I'm running OpenSSH Version 7.6 on macOS High Sierra (Mac OS X Version 10.13.6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh-keygen -r` generates a [SSHFP record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFP_record). That's something you put in a [DNS entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) to say indicate the **host** key corresponding to a host name. This allows someone who wants to log into your machine to know what host key to expect, assuming that they trust the DNS record (which in practice means that it must be obtained using [DNSSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions)).

So naturally `ssh-keygen -r` looks for the host key of your machine. It isn't interested in a user key — if you force it to read a user key, it might work, but the result isn't useful. `ssh-keygen -r` looks at `/etc/ssh_host_*_key.pub`, or wherever the SSH server has been configured to look for the host's keys. If you don't have an SSH server set up on your machine, you have no use for an SSHFP record, so it isn't a problem that `ssh-keygen -r` doesn't find a key.